# why cpu not balance when multiprocess epoll on the same socket?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, linux-kernel, epoll

I hava a high performance server receiving incoming connections, The master process listen/bind on the tcp port, and fork itself to some workers. 
The workers then use epoll to watch the incoming connection event, try to accept connection if event happens.

it works well, but when I count the connections each workers handled(or the CPU utils each worker consumed), I found it not balance at all.

for example:

One Busy Worker: handling 10k connections, and consumer 20% CPU;
One Idle Worker: handling 300 conenctions, and consumer 4% CPU;

My server running on a RHEL6.5 OS(2.6.32 kernel).

Would anyone can help me on this issue?

---

**EDITED:**

### Why

After digging some kernel code(2.6.32.x), I found why the in-balance occures.

1 * MasterProcess:create and bind Listen socket;
n * WorkerPrecess:create epfd and monitor the listen socket from master.

When WorkProcess epoll_ctl(..., listen_sock,...), the kernel add the watch file to a rbtree of the epoll struct(@see fs/eventpoll.c ep_insert) and add the epoll struct to a wait_queue of the listen_sock by a callback (ep_ptable_queue_proc)

```
static void ep_ptable_queue_proc(struct file *file, wait_queue_head_t *whead,
             poll_table *pt) {
    ...
    add_wait_queue(whead, &pwq->wait);
    ...    
}
//whead is the waitqueue of listen socket, 
//and the *pt is a container of epfd's releated resource.
```

when a new connection is incoming(SYN_REC), the listen socket's event has been changed, kernel will *iterator the waitqueue* to notify the event to all epoll monitor on the socket by a callback given by epoll. the callback is *ep_poll_callback* (@see fs/eventpoll.c), and the callback will wake up the Process(or Thread) wait on epoll_wait system call.

The sequences of listen socket's waitqueue will not change after the notify process. and the processes wait on the events will get notified with a *fixed* order. The process wake up early shall have more connections to handle vs the the last process get notified. That causes the in-balance.

### FIX

1 * MasterProcess create a epfd for all WorkerProcess;
2 * WorkerProcess wait on the same epfd by epoll_wait;

in this case, we have only *one* epoll struct at all in the kernel level. When event occurs, only *one* epoll struct's wait up call_back will be called.

the epoll struct's wake up callback is:

```
static int ep_poll_callback(wait_queue_t *wait, unsigned mode, int sync, void *key)
```

Right now, all WorkerProcess's boss thread is wait on epoll_wait, and the ep_poll_callback will *only* wake up one of them.

While a WorkerProcess wake up by epoll, it will remove itself from the wait_queue, and re-add them self to the tail of wait_queue if epoll_wait is called. So, we can wake up WorkerProcess one by one.

Comment: On what basis does the master choose the worker from the worker pool?

Comment: Master doesn't choose worker, worker listen on the socket inherited from master process .

Comment: Post some code. You would expect the one that's less busy to get to `epoll()` and `accept()` first, but it's a race, and you need to defend correctly against losing the race, i.e. `accept()` causing EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK. I'd be interested to see how you are handling all that.

Comment: sharing the epfd is the right way to go, otherwise there is no benefit to just use select. but keep in mind that the process that get woken up is "the last to call poll()". so if you have 2 process PID1, PID2, and PID2 call it last, PID2 will get woken, if a new event comes while PID2 is processing the previous, PID1 will be called... BUT if no event comes and PID2 finishes, and call poll() again, then the next event will wake PID2. this can cause unbalance in the processes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem.

The purpose of having multiple workers is for at least one to available, even if the others are busy.

But when multiple workers are waiting, it does not matter which one gets the event. A process/thread does not wear out simply because it's running for a longer time.

There is no balance because the kernel does not care. Neither should you.

Comment: I've found a solution on this. If all the worker inherited epfd from master instead create one by their own(epoll_cteate). All workers will almost handle the same amount of requests.

Comment: I have to care about this issue because the balance of connections handle by each process concurrently is very import to my server.